# Spring switch between 2 transaction managers (no single transaction behavior needed)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

To access 2 databases, we are using two different transaction managers (each with its own datasource):

First transaction manager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Second transaction manager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager2"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory2" />
</bean>
```

On the service layer, we would like to have a method that gets an id and returns a DTO. The problem is that the DTO must be filled with data from both databases.

We tried this first approach:

- FooDao: uses sessionFactory (the same as transactionManager)
- BarDao: use sessionFactory2 (the same sessionFactory as transactionManager2)

With the following service methods:

```
@Autowired
private FooDao fooDao;

@Autowired
private BarDao barDao;

@Transactional(value="transactionManager", readOnly=true)
public FooBarDto getFoo(int id) {
    Foo foo = fooDao.get(id);

    return createDto(foo);
}

@Transactional(value="transactionManager2", readOnly=true)
public FooBarDto createDto(Foo foo) {
    Bar bar = barDao.get(foo.getId());

    FooBarDto fooBarDto = new FooBarDto();

    fooBarDto.setId(String.valueOf(foo.getId()));
    fooBarDto.setA(String.valueOf(foo.getA()));
    fooBarDto.setB(String.valueOf(foo.getB()));
    fooBarDto.setC(String.valueOf(bar.getC()));
    fooBarDto.setD(String.valueOf(bar.getD()));

    return fooBarDto;
}
```

But in this case we get the "no session found for current thread" error in the barDao method. Since we don't need the whole operation on a single transaction (and to keep our current configuration) we would prefer not to use JTA.

We tried to configure transaction propagation (with Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) but looks like it works only for transactions from the same manager.

We could change these two methods and call both of them (sequentially) from the controller, but we would prefer to call a single service method to do all the work. Is there any way of achieving the expected behavior?

---

Thanks a lot Ricardo Veguilla! Following your suggestions, everything is working fine now. I moved the createDto method to another service (BarService) and autowired it on the first Service (FooService):

```
@Service
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

    @Autowired
    private FooDao fooDao;

    @Autowired
    private BarService barService;

    @Transactional(value="transactionManager", readOnly=true)
    public FooBarDto getFoo(int id) {
        Foo foo = fooDao.get(id);

        return barService.createDto(foo);
    }
}
```

And the created BarService:

```
@Service
public class BarServiceImpl implements BarService {

    @Autowired
    private BarDao barDao;

    @Transactional(value="transactionManager2", readOnly=true)
    public FooBarDto createDto(Foo foo) {
        FooBarDto fooBarDto = new FooBarDto();

        if (foo != null) {
            Bar bar = barDao.get(foo.getId());

            fooBarDto.setId(String.valueOf(foo.getId()));
            fooBarDto.setA(String.valueOf(foo.getA()));
            fooBarDto.setB(String.valueOf(foo.getB()));

            if (bar != null) {
                fooBarDto.setC(String.valueOf(bar.getC()));
                fooBarDto.setD(String.valueOf(bar.getD()));
            }
        }

        return fooBarDto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting no session in `barDao` bacuse you are calling `createDto` from inside the same bean, which means the method invocation does not go through Spring Transacitional proxy.

In Spring, a bean `myBean` with a public method annotated with `@Transactional` needs to be invoke from some other bean that contains a Spring injected `myBean` instance, since the transaction support is implemented using a Proxy. You need to move `createDto` method to another bean:

```
 @component
 public class ForBarService {

        @Autowired
        private FooDao fooDao;

        @Autowired
        private DtoFactory dtoFactory;

        @Transactional(value="transactionManager", readOnly=true)
        public FooBarDto getFoo(int id) {
        Foo foo = fooDao.get(id);
             return dtoFactory.createDto(foo);
        }
 }

 @Component
 public class DtoFactory {
      @Autowired
      private BarDao barDao;

      @Transactional(value="transactionManager2", readOnly=true)
      public FooBarDto createDto(Foo foo) {
          Bar bar = barDao.get(foo.getId());

          FooBarDto fooBarDto = new FooBarDto();

          fooBarDto.setId(String.valueOf(foo.getId()));
          fooBarDto.setA(String.valueOf(foo.getA()));
          fooBarDto.setB(String.valueOf(foo.getB()));
          fooBarDto.setC(String.valueOf(bar.getC()));
          fooBarDto.setD(String.valueOf(bar.getD()));

          return fooBarDto;
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 you can create class like:

```
@Component
class TransactionWrapper {

    @Transactional
    public <T> T doInTransaction(Supplier<T> supplier) {
       return
    }
```

To call methods inside class (ie private ones) in transaction context.

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide an example?